# Why this java SQLException?

Tags: java, sql, exception, jdbc

I'm trying to update a table using 2 other table. This is the program:

```
private void getTickersByNames(String fromtable, String totable) {
    try {
        String ticker;
        con = mhjexcel.con;

        sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + totable;
        Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(sql);

        rs2.beforeFirst();
        while (rs2.next()) {
            String name = rs2.getString("name");
            sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + fromtable + " where name = '" + name + "'";
            Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);
            rs1.first();
            if (rs1.getRow() == 0) {
                out("the name is not in 1st table" + name);
                rs1.close();
                stmt1.close();
                Statement stmt3 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                fromtable = "tsetmc";
                sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + fromtable + " where name = '" + name + "'";
                ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql);
                rs3.first();
                if (rs3.getRow() == 0) {
                    out("the name is not in second too");
                    rs3.close();
                    stmt3.close();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    ticker = rs3.getString("ticker");
                    rs3.close();
                    stmt3.close();
                    out(ticker);
                    out(rs2.getRow());
                    rs2.absolute(rs2.getRow());
                    rs2.updateString("ticker", ticker);
                    rs2.updateRow();
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                ticker = rs1.getString("ticker");
                rs1.close();
                stmt1.close();
                rs2.updateString("ticker", ticker);
                rs2.updateRow();
            }
        }
        rs2.close();
        stmt2.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Frame_Ticker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

and this is the Exception:

> SEVERE: null
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state - no current row.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

I look a lot... statement is not closed... result set is not closed... the **rs2.getRow() returns 1** ... rs2.updateString() works... but **rs2.updateRow() doesn't work** ... I don't understand... maybe I should not use some result set together!?

thanks for your help.

### EDIT

I finally found the answer and it's provided in this page.

Comment: 3 queries looping? Whatever you try to do - you do it wrong.

Comment: hi @juergend . why it's wrong? is it forbidden to use 3 queries?

Comment: @juergend - I'm only making loop over rs2! not others.

Comment: You... don't loop a query. You retrieve the rows you need and loop over the ResultSet.

Comment: For something which is like a timer (immediate tracking), it makes no sense to update something expensive like a database vs something in-memory such as a `Map`

Comment: I did not got your answer well... what should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was from here (as I found) **that three query statement can not use 1 connection** as I had in my program:

```
con = mhjexcel.con;
Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
Statement stmt3 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

so I changed it like below and it worked:

```
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mhjtestdatabase", null, null);
Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mhjtestdatabase", null, null);
Connection con3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mhjtestdatabase", null, null);
Statement stmt2 = con2.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
Statement stmt3 = con3.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

the whole program if you want:

```
private void getTickersByNames(String fromtable, String totable) {
    try {
        String ticker;
        Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mhjtestdatabase", null, null);
        Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mhjtestdatabase", null, null);
        Connection con3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mhjtestdatabase", null, null);

        sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + totable;
        Statement stmt2 = con2.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(sql);

        rs2.beforeFirst();
        while (rs2.next()) {
            String name = rs2.getString("name");
            sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + fromtable + " where name = '" + name + "'";
            Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);
            rs1.first();
            if (rs1.getRow() == 0) {
                out("the name is not in 1st table" + name);
                rs1.close();
                stmt1.close();
                Statement stmt3 = con3.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                fromtable = "tsetmc";
                sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + fromtable + " where name = '" + name + "'";
                ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql);
                rs3.first();
                if (rs3.getRow() == 0) {
                    out("the name is not in second too");
                    rs3.close();
                    stmt3.close();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    ticker = rs3.getString("ticker");
                    rs3.close();
                    stmt3.close();
                    rs2.updateString("ticker", ticker);
                    rs2.updateRow();
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                ticker = rs1.getString("ticker");
                rs1.close();
                stmt1.close();
                rs2.updateString("ticker", ticker);
                rs2.updateRow();
            }
        }
        rs2.close();
        stmt2.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Frame_Ticker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes... maybe because the result set was created before! so there were no need to connections for reading... but for writting there should be a new statement and connection!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have got a connection leak for `Statement stmt3 = con.createStatement()`, because without closing the previous `Statement` `stmt3`, you are creating a new statement object and assigning to `stmt3`.

You should always close the `statement` object, before assigning a new `statement` `object` **to the same reference variable**, otherwise, you will loose the reference and will NOT be able `close` the first statement object, which causes the connection leak.

Also, YOU ARE OPENING RESULTSELTS INSIDE THE WHILE, BUT CLOSING ONLY ONE RESULTSET (FINAL ONE) AT THE END, WHICH IS INCORRECT, you can look at the below code:

```
private void getTickersByNames(String fromtable, String totable) {
        try {
            String ticker;
            con = mhjexcel.con;
            Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);

            sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + totable;
            Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(sql);

            Statement stmt3 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql);;

            rs2.beforeFirst();
            while (rs2.next()) {
                String name = rs2.getString("name");
                sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + fromtable + " where name = '" + name + "'";
                try {
                rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);
                rs1.first();
                if (rs1.getRow() == 0) {
                    out("the name is not in 1st table" + name);

                    fromtable = "tsetmc";
                    sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + fromtable + " where name = '" + name + "'";
                    rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql);
                    rs3.first();
                    if (rs3.getRow() == 0) {
                        out("the name is not in second too");
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        ticker = rs3.getString("ticker");
                        out(ticker);
                        out(rs2.getRow());
                        rs2.absolute(rs2.getRow());
                        rs2.updateString("ticker", ticker);
                        rs2.updateRow();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                ticker = rs1.getString("ticker");
                rs2.updateString("ticker", ticker);
                rs2.updateRow();
                } catch(SQLException sql) {
                     Logger.getLogger(Frame_Ticker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } finally {
                    if(rs3 != null) {
                    rs3.close();
                    }
                    if(rs1 != null) {
                    rs1.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            if(rs3 != null) {
                rs3.close();
                }
                if(rs1 != null) {
                rs1.close();
                }

                if(rs2 != null) {
                    rs2.close();
                    }

                if(stmt1 != null) {
                    stmt1.close();
                    }
                if(stmt2 != null) {
                    stmt2.close();
                    }
                if(stmt3 != null) {
                    stmt3.close();
                    }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Frame_Ticker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi @javaguy ;  I didn't get your answer well, but I have done as you said and nothing happened,

Comment: Why are you assigning createStatement() object two times to stmt3 ?

Comment: Before assigning the second statement object to the same reference (stmt3), you need close the first statement object

Comment: that was a mistake...I've removed it now and I have only one... but problem still exist... :(

Comment: hi @javaguy ; the problem is not from closing and opening of queries or result sets. why? because I have tested them by `out(rs2.isclosed())` `stmt2.is....` and others... (`out` is `system.out.println`) + also I have changed the program with another configuration that I have putted it in the first post of this page by header: **EDIT** + comment below

Comment: also I found out there is no problem when I point to another row of result set!!! for example if i add `rs2.last();` before `rs2.updateString("ticker", ticker);` `rs2.updateRow();` the program works without any exception!!! maybe its weakness of derby that can not update a row that is just got!

Comment: by the way... I found the problem and posted it.... but I don't know why did I got downvote???